# how to implement same functions in different languages?

Tags: auto-generate

I have a REST interface.

Now I want to have a client for ruby, javascript, python and java (and maybe more in the future)

Currently I am maintaining 4 different projects and their tests.

How can I improve this and what tools can I use?

currently I am starting to describe the API in a file (e.g. yaml/json) and then generate sources for each language by some logic specific to language, but that is a lot of work, and I am certain I am not the first to run into this issue.

I searched the web for `generate source from yaml` and such but couldn't find anything

*edit:* someone suggested I'd use yeoman. so currently I am investigating that.

Comment: I see someone voted this question as 'off topic'. I just like to note that the guide specifically says I can ask about "software tools commonly used by programmers" which is the topic of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) as a tool is good for that. You can specify an API endpoint and generate clients for multiple languages.